# How to get the user who has the most advertisements in the last 30 days?

Tags: sql, mysql, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have two tables in my database as below:

categories table:

| Column Name | Column Type |
| --- | --- |
| ID | INT |
| Name | TEXT |
| IDParent | DOUBLE |

and advertisements table:

| Column Name | Column Type |
| --- | --- |
| ID | INT |
| IDUser | INT |
| DateAdded | DATETIME |
| IDCategory | INT |
| Price | DOUBLE |

I have a task in my project as below:

`The user ID of the user who has the most ads in the period of one month (thirty days) in the real estate consultant category (including Estate) for each advertiser.`

my code is:

```
SELECT IDUser
FROM (
    SELECT a1.IDUser,
           COUNT(a2.ID) AS AdCount
    FROM advertisements a1
    INNER JOIN advertisements a2 ON a1.IDUser = a2.IDUser
    INNER JOIN categories c ON a2.IDCategory = c.ID
    WHERE c.Name LIKE '%Estate%'
    AND a2.DateAdded BETWEEN a1.DateAdded AND DATE_ADD(a1.DateAdded, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    GROUP BY a1.IDUser, a1.DateAdded
) AS Sub
GROUP BY IDUser
ORDER BY MAX(AdCount) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

my code problem:

I think my code has a problem: it doesn't calculate for All thirty days

and
I also want to override the code and use window functions

can you help me to do this?

Comment: Hi. Please clarify MySQL's version, and add some test data in the form of `insert` statetements .

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query,

```
SELECT IDUser, max(AdCount) FROM
(SELECT a1.IDUser as IDUser, COUNT(a1.ID) AS AdCount
    FROM advertisements a1
    INNER JOIN categories c ON a1.IDCategory = c.ID
    WHERE c.Name LIKE '%Estate%'
    AND a1.DateAdded >= a1.DateAdded - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    GROUP BY a1.IDUser) T1 group by IDUser;
```

Comment: You've got aggregate function (`max(AdCount)`) with non-aggregated column (`IDUser`) without a `GROUP BY`. That mat produce false results as MySQL is free to pick any `IDUser`.

Comment: your solution is incorrect
the error:
Unknown column 'a2.IDCategory' in 'on clause'

Comment: Its a typo error, just change a2 to a1, edited the query

Answer (score 0):

```
`WITH UserAdCounts AS (
    SELECT IDUser,
           COUNT(*) AS AdCount,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS RankByAdCount
    FROM Advertisements
    WHERE IDCategory IN (SELECT ID FROM Categories WHERE Name LIKE '%Estate%')
          AND DateAdded BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
    GROUP BY IDUser
)
SELECT IDUser
FROM UserAdCounts
WHERE RankByAdCount = 1;`
```

The above is the query that I have solved on a sample dataset using the window function. If my approach is wrong, please suggest what went wrong.